# Resolving SQL Error: ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Tags: sql, oracle

I executed the following SQL code and created a table:

```
create table empnew 
(
    empno number(25) primary key not null,
    ename varchar(25) not null,
    deptno number(25) not null,
    salary number(25) not null,
    commision number (25) default '10'
);
```

I want to input values using `&`. I executed the following:

```
insert into empnew values(&empno,&ename,&deptno,&salary,&commision);
```

But I get the error:

> ORA-01008: not all variables bound

What is the proper use of `&` to resolve this error message?

Comment: Please give your question a meaningful title!!

Answer (score 1):

The following code ready to execute in SQL*Plus represents the following steps:

- activate substitution variables
- define/reset the prefix for substitution variables
- define all substitution variables (types are deduced from the specification of literals)
- launch the DML statement (note the added single quotes around `&ename`; Substitution variables represent literal values. They do not change the SQL syntax (e.g. enclosing literal string values with single quotes).

  ```
  set define on
  set define '&'
  define empno = 123
  define ename = "HR"
  define deptno = 456
  define salary = 40000
  define commission = 0.14
  insert into empnew values ( &empno, '&ename', &deptno, &salary, &commission);
  ```

The details on the usage of substitution values and the syntax rules to obey can be found in the [Official Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_five.htm#SQPUG015).

(Friendly) Hint: Do not expect to excel in your work with Oracle DBs unless you routinely study the docs.